# net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException: Broken transport; encountered EOF

Tags: scala, exception, sftp, file-transfer

I am using `"com.hierynomus" % "sshj" % "0.13.0"` to transfer a file from local server to sftp server

File is getting tranferred without any problem but I am getting below error on console :

```
[error] n.s.s.t.TransportImpl - Dying because - {}
net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException: Broken transport; encountered EOF
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Reader.run(Reader.java:58) ~[sshj-0.13.0.jar:na]
```

Code :

```
      val ssh = new SSHClient()
      ssh.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier())
      ssh.connect(props.host)
      ssh.authPassword(props.username, props.password)
      val client=ssh.newSFTPClient()
      client.put(localDirectory + fileName, remoteDirectory)
```

Please suggest me the cause for the same